# Show the inverse is an open set

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I'm having trouble understanding how to prove this. Can someone help me figure it out?

If $f: D \rightarrow \mathbb R $ is a continuous function and $I = (c, d)$ is an interval in $\mathbb R$, show that $f^{-1}(I)$ is an open set in $D$.

Now I know that $f^{-1} = \{x\in D : f(x) \in (c, d)\}$ but I'm not sure how to use it to prove that $f^{-1}(I)$ is an open set.

Comment: The most common definition of continuity is that for any open set $A$, $f^{-1}(A)$ is an open set.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x\in f^{-1}(I)$ then, $f(x)\in I$ and it has a positive distance, say $\varepsilon$, from the endpoints of $I$. By continuity, for this $\varepsilon$, there is a $\delta$ such that the neighborhood of radius $\delta$ around $x$ (i.e. $(x-\delta,x+\delta)$) still totally lies in $f^{-1}(I)$.